# Formatação de moeda em cálculo de input

Tags: jquery, maskmoney

A ideia do script está correta.
Só não consegui colocar a formatação de moeda no campo "preco_minimo_n" (com script valor).
Se eu coloco a formatação de moeda real nesse input, ele não calcula.

```js
   $(function(){
    $(".valor").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
   }) 
      
   $(function() {
    $('#preco_minimo_n').on('input', function() {
     Number.prototype.formataReal = function(c, d, t) {
      var n = this,
       c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
       d = d == undefined ? "," : d,
       t = t == undefined ? "." : t,
       s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
       i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
       j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
      return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
     };
     
     var $preco_minimo = $(this);
     var $preco_minimo_b     = $("#preco_minimo_n").val(); 
     var $preco_minimo_c   = parseFloat($preco_minimo_b.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
  
     var $table = $preco_minimo.closest('div');
     
     //var $preco_estimado = $table.find("#preco_estimado_n");
     var $preco_estimado_b   = $("#preco_estimado_n").val();
     var $preco_estimado_c = parseFloat($preco_estimado_b.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))     
     
     var $percentual_desconto = $table.find("#percentual_desconto_n");

     //var preco_estimado = parseFloat((1 / 10).toFixed(1));
     //$preco_estimado.val(preco_estimado);
     //$percentual_desconto.val(parseFloat($preco_minimo.val()) + preco_estimado);
     $percentual_desconto.val(parseFloat((($preco_minimo_c / $preco_estimado_c) - 1) * 100).formataReal(2, ',', '.') + ' %');
    });
   });
```

```html
<script src="http://www.rpgigasolucoes.com.br/beta/mmlicitacoes/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.rpgigasolucoes.com.br/beta/mmlicitacoes/js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>


<div>


   <p>
    <b>Preço mínimo</b>
    <input type="text" name="preco_minimo_n" id="preco_minimo_n" class="amount ">
   </p>
          
   <p>
    <b>Preço estimado</b>
    <input name="preco_estimado_n" id="preco_estimado_n" type="text" class="tax valor" value="R$ 590.000,00" readonly="readonly">
   </p>
       
   <p>
    <b>Percentual de desconto</b>
    <input name="percentual_desconto_n" id="percentual_desconto_n" type="text" class="total valor" readonly="readonly">
   </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: ja tentou retirar a formação pra calcular?

Comment: $(".valor") não vi essa classe no seu HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não descobri o erro no seu código mas descobri um jeito de fazer funcionar**

**Script**

```
$(function(){
   $(".amount").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
})  

$( document ).ready(function() {

Number.prototype.formataReal = function(c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
    d = d == undefined ? "," : d,
    t = t == undefined ? "." : t,
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};

var preco_minimo = $("#preco_minimo_n");
preco_minimo.keyup( function(){

var $preco_estimado_b   = $("#preco_estimado_n").val();
var $preco_estimado_c = parseFloat($preco_estimado_b.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))                    
                    
$preco_minimo_b = (preco_minimo.val());

var $preco_minimo_c = parseFloat($preco_minimo_b.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));

$("#percentual_desconto_n").val(parseFloat((($preco_minimo_c / $preco_estimado_c) - 1) * 100).formataReal(2, ',', '.') + ' %');
    
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
<b>Preço mínimo</b>
   <input type="text" name="preco_minimo_n" id="preco_minimo_n" class="amount">
</p>
          
<p>
<b>Preço estimado</b>
   <input name="preco_estimado_n" id="preco_estimado_n" type="text" class="tax valor" value="R$ 590.000,00" readonly="readonly">
</p>
       
<p>
<b>Percentual de desconto</b>
   <input name="percentual_desconto_n" id="percentual_desconto_n" type="text" class="total valor" readonly="readonly">
</p>
```

> - **Correção** ao invés de `$(".valor").maskMoney({` o correto é `$(".amount").maskMoney({`

Comment: Apresentei o projeto e o cliente conseguiu encontrar um bo que jamais eu iria encontrar. O cálculo está perfeito, porém, ela simulou com preço estimado de R$ 1.000.000,00 e acredito eu que a expressão regular dá algum conflito, pois, se eu der um alert, retorna 1000. Aí o cálculo fica maluco.